# Infinitest and IDEA 10

Tags: intellij-idea, infinitest

Has anyone managed to get the new Infinitest open source version running in IntelliJ IDEA 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest version of Infinitest works well on IDEA 10. Version 5.1.87 can be found here: http://infinitest.github.com/

The version proposed by the plugins wizard is outdated, do you have to manually decompress infinitest into IDEA's *plugins* folder. On OSX, the *plugins* folder can be found by right-clicking on Intellij icon, *Show Package Content*

Once its decompressed, start Intellij and make sure to add the Infinitest facet to your project/module.

Comment: "make sure to add the Infinitest facet to your project/module."
This was the essential bit missing from every infopage on the internet. Thanks a bunch! The plugin you get through the Wizard is updated btw. No need to roll your own.

Answer (score 1):

The IDEA plugin repository is now up-to-date.
You can install it from the IDEA Plugins manager